# Electron App - Divide main process into several files and share variable

Tags: javascript, class, electron

I'm developing an app with Electron, but I have a problem to exchange a variable between several files.

In my main.js, I create an RxDB database that is used for my entire project. At this level, I also create handlers allowing the communication between the main process and the render process via IPC. These handlers call various Classes that perform various processes including database insertions, modifications, etc.

In my opinion, I haven't found an efficient way to transmit my variable containing my database to my classes.

Ideally, I should be able to call this database variable (declared in `main.js`) at any time from any class. I can't use the IPC system because my returned variable must not be a JSON but absolutely an RxDatabase object.

Here is a very simplified diagram of my main process:

[image: Diagram of my main process]

Currently, to share my database variable to my classes:

- I declare the variable in `main.js`
- I transmit the variable in the handlers
- I transmit the variable to my classes in a static variable class

Although ugly, this system works. But I think there is a more correct way to do it. Also, it becomes difficult to preserve this variable when a class calls one or more instances of external classes.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just using `module.export` and then importing it in the other classes?

Comment: It was so simple, thanks Luke! 
I had already tried this method but when I tried to do `export {database}`, I had an _Unexpeted token export error_. So I had assumed that it would be impossible for me to export a variable from main.js for some obscure reasons specific to Electron. In fact, I just had to use a ES5 syntax, that way `exports.database = database`. Then in any file I can call `import { database } from 'main'` and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `exports.variable = variable` and then `import { variable } from 'file'` in the other file.

Comment: This is a life saver for me, thank you Luke!

Answer (score 3):

A simple export / import  is enough.

Previously, I tried to export my variable from *main.js* but when I tried to use `export {database}`, I had an `Unexpeted token export error`.So I had assumed that it would be impossible for me to export a variable from main.js for some obscure reasons specific to Electron.

In fact, you just need to use a ES5 syntax, that way `exports.database = database` in *main.js*.
Then, you can import this variable in any file of your main process.

**Thanks @Luke for his answer.**